# Using opencv how to obtain the second brightest region of an image?

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently trying to detect both; the cup and the disc of an image of Glaucoma. They way these two stand out from the rest of the image is they're brighter than the rest of the image. But the cup is brighter than the disc, so I'm only able to detect the cup. What I want to achieve is, to encircle both; the cup and the disc with two different circles. The cup being the brightest of the image, and disc the second brightest. How do I ago about doing it?

Here's my code (only detects cup and encircles it. I' trying to detect both; cup and disc, and encircle them both with different circles.)

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (args["radius"], args["radius"]), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, args["radius"], (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.namedWindow("Test", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Test", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm also trying to do it without the radius being manually inputted. Do share if you have an idea for that.

Here's a sample image of a Glaucoma. The brightest part in the circle is the cup, and the bigger circle surrounding it is the disc.[image: Here's a sample image of a Glaucoma showing cup and disc.]

Comment: 1. try to group your pixels based on their intensities, say using k-means, and you may find the disk that way. 2. It looks like disk and rest of the Glaucoma has a distinct circular edge. You can first calculate the edge image and find circle in that image.

Comment: @DXM How do I get the edge image? I tried, but I get the edge of the glaucoma itself.

Comment: Are the outside totally dark? Calculate a mask for the Glaucoma, you can try to apply to mask either before or after the edge detection. If you already tried Canny edge detection, you can also try just calculating the gradient of the image, using sobel or other operator.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem tracking objects with some colours. My approach would be the next:

1. Using [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0), manage to create an image where everything is black -> 0 and disc and cup are white -> 255
2. Once you have that part done, using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html), you can compute radious automatically

[In my repository](https://github.com/ezequielo/Robotics-Lab/tree/master/src/visionchallenge/src) I have some code (although it's C++ because it was a ROS project) where I use it in order to track a blue object.

The advantage of using threshold and moments is that if you image is a little bit turned, with zoom or even in movement, you can still track the desired object and calculate elements like radius, center, etc

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, but what if I have an image where the brightest part is neither the disc or the cup? In that case thresholding may not work, would it?

Comment: It is not about brightness, you need to isolate that color, in this case: yellow. I believe this solution is enough good for your problem.